# Naming clipped files from layer mask?

Tags: qgis, raster, layers, clip, masking

I have to clip a quite large raster (corn crops) into individuals rows. It's working fine with the "Clip raster by mask layer" tool with a grid I created.

However, I need the clipped images to be named after the mask feature that's been used.

I've created a new feature in the grid so every cell is named how I want it to.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Maybe splitting the mask layer into several layers each containing a single feature, then clipping the raster using batch processing and your attribute could work.

Comment: I've tried this but I dont now what expression/formula to use to name the output file after the mask..

Answer (score 2):

If you've split the grid into individual layers that are saved in a directory, then you can select that directory (using Autofill...) as the *Mask layer* field for **Clip raster by mask layer** tool in Batch Processing mode.

[image]

Then for the *Clipped (mask)* field, select Autofill... -> Calculate by expression, and use an expression like:

`file_path(@MASK) + '\\' + base_file_name(@MASK)+'.tif'`

to translate the mask filenames into corresponding output filenames. Obviously you may need to play with the details to get it to work for your filesystem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyqgis and iterate over each polygon, create a temp mask layer using its id, clip using the mask layer:

```py
import os
output_raster_folder = r"C:\temp\test" #Adjust
rasterlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("land_use")[0] #Adjust
vectorlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("clip_layer")[0] #Adjust
name_field="name" #Adjust

for feature in vectorlayer.getFeatures(): #For each polygon in vectorlayer
    
    #Create a temp layer using current feature id
    masklayer = vectorlayer.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(feature.id()))
    name = next(masklayer.getFeatures())[name_field] #Fetch its name from name_field

    print(f"Clipping polygon: {name}")
    #Create output raster name using the name: #Example: 'C:\\temp\\test\\clip_c669.tif'
    output_raster = os.path.join(output_raster_folder, f"clip_{name}.tif") #Adjust if you want to 
    
    #Clip using the temp layer of only one polygon feature
    processing.run("gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer", {'INPUT':rasterlayer,
    'MASK':masklayer,'SOURCE_CRS':None,'TARGET_CRS':None,'TARGET_EXTENT':None,
    'NODATA':None,'ALPHA_BAND':False,'CROP_TO_CUTLINE':True,
    'KEEP_RESOLUTION':False,'SET_RESOLUTION':False,'X_RESOLUTION':None,
    'Y_RESOLUTION':None,'MULTITHREADING':False,'OPTIONS':'COMPRESS=LZW',
    'DATA_TYPE':0,'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':output_raster})
```

[image]